# Is there a way to use Skype on iPad with audio chat only?

Tags: ipad, skype

I'm having first version of iPad and a USB headphone. is it possible to use skype on iPad? I'm on Wi-Fi.

Answer (score 1):

I was using Skype on my 3rd gen iPod for audio calls, so I wont think you'll have have any problems using it on a 1st gen iPad.

Comment: but no skype application for iPad in apple store.

Comment: There isn't but you can install the iPod/iPhone version on your iPad. Download the app via iTunes, and then sync it to your iPad.

Comment: ok. but i think audio chat is not possible on ipad because no USB port available

Comment: @jitendra-vyas You may use iPad's built-in microphone, or use the earbuds with microphone which came with your iPad. Alternatively, there is a USB adapter for the iPad, but I'm not sure if it's compatible with headsets.

Comment: can i do voice chat from ipad without having earphone and external mic. Is inbuilt mic availabe inside ipad?

Comment: The pinhole next to the headphone port is the iPad's microphone.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use USB Headset with an iOS device, however, you can use Skype on your iPad with the iPhone headset or with the integrated mic and speaker.

Comment: USB headsets do work with the Camera Connection Kit.